# Add calendar to iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on an application which needs a calendar in it. Which could be a better approach:

1. Creating my own calendar
2. Using a 3rd party calendar (Cocoapods eg.)

Comment: There is no built-in calendar framework.  If you're asking how to make one from scratch, that question is way too broad.  Creating day cells with a `UICollectionView` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a page called [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) where you cand find stuff like this.

Maybe you are not interested in knowing new sites and stuff so I will let you know [the options](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar).

As you can see there are lots of libraries/projects that provide classes for you to implement a calendar, [Tapkulibrary](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) is the most used, cause is the most accurate related to iOS native calendar and, the most complete.

You will need the [documentation](http://devinsheaven.com/tapku/documentation/) to work with this library.

It provides delegates and methods for you to take full advantage (Example of methods to get when a user taps on a date or change of month, etc.):

```
#pragma mark MonthView Delegate & DataSource
- (NSArray*) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate*)startDate toDate:(NSDate*)lastDate{
    [self generateRandomDataForStartDate:startDate endDate:lastDate];
    return self.dataArray;
}
- (void) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate*)date{
    NSLog(@"Date Selected: %@",date);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)mv monthDidChange:(NSDate*)d animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super calendarMonthView:mv monthDidChange:d animated:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope it helps.